# What is zombie transaction?

Tags: sql-server, transactions

I accidentally found `zombie transaction` is mentioned in `SqlTransaction` code. So, what is zombie transaction?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A zombie transaction is a transaction that cannot be committed (due to an unrecoverable error) but is still open.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
                INSERT
                INTO    mytable
                VALUES  (1)
                INSERT
                INTO    mytable
                VALUES  (1)
        COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT XACT_STATE()
        SELECT  *
        FROM    mytable
        ROLLBACK;
END CATCH
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
```

Here, the second `INSERT` renders the transaction zombie.

It cannot write anymore and should be rolled back, but you can still read in its scope (the innermost `SELECT` returns a record; the outermost does not).

Comment: And you need a machete or shotgun to get rid of it!...Man, I love I.T. work. 80)